# MySQL data truncated

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to store prices in my database. I have set the column to DECIMAL(2,2) and trying to insert 2.10. When I run the insert statement I get 2 warnings:

"Data truncated for column price at row 1"
and
"Out of range value for column price at row 1"

Anyone got any ideas as to what may be causing the warnings?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read up on decimal type in mysql. In MySQL `DECIMAL(2,2)` means maximum two digits, with two digits to the right of the decimal separator. Which basically means all your digits are to the right of the dot.

If you want two digits with two decimal points, you should use `DECIMAL(4,2)` which means four digits total, out of that two are to the right of the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks D. Kasipovic but I'm still left with the data truncated warning

Comment: Did you change your field type? WHat did you change it to and what are you trying to insert?

Comment: yes I put it to `price DECIMAL(4,2)` and trying to insert 2.10

Comment: As I said **DECIMAL(2,2) means two digits, both to the right of the dot**. It means that you can only insert `0.xx`. If you want to insert 2.10 you need to use `DECIMAL(3,2)`. That means three digits total, where two are to the right of the dot. That is what you have. Three digits: 210, where 1 and 0 are to the right of the dot. **left of the dot ->2 . 10 <-right of the dot**.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion that was a typo on my part I have it at (4,2). I tried (3,2) but still makes no difference

Comment: Sure `INSERT INTO price(product, price) VALUES("milk", 2.10);`

Comment: And `DESCRIBE price`?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE price (
 price_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 product CHAR(10),
 price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: 1 queries executed, 1 success, 0 errors, 0 warnings

Query: INSERT INTO price(product, price) VALUES("milk", 2.10)

This is what I am getting. I do not see why would you be getting warnings. Do you maybe have some triggers that are executed before/after insert that could generate warnings?

Comment: No warnings here my friend, using your create table syntax and your insert statement.

Comment: All is good now guys, just restarted workbench, thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want `DECIMAL(4,2)` if you mean to store up to `99.99`.

The first part is the number is the maximum number of total digits, often called the "significance" of the number. The second part is the number of digits after the decimal point, often called the "precision". So, 4 total digits, 2 to the right of the decimal gives a max of `99.99`

---

Sidebar: you should almost always have more significance than this. A good standard is `DECIMAL(13,2)` which allows you to store dollar amounts up to $99,999,999,999.99, or just under a hundred billion dollars.

Comment: Thanks mellowfish87 but I'm still left with the data truncated warning

Comment: That is very strange... also: where are you running these commands that you see the warnings?

Comment: MySQL Workbench, I even tried (13,2) but still got the same result

Comment: Very strange, I turned on warnings for my sql editor and I can see them when I insert 2.011, but not 2.10 or 2.01. Are you quite sure the column type is changing?

Comment: I know, I can't understand it either, yes the column is changing ok

Answer (score 0):

The format is `DECIMAL(M,D)`, where `M` is the maximum number of digits for the column and `D` is the number of decimal places, so 10.5 will be DECIMAL(3,1) for example. You probably need DECIMAL(4,2) as a column specification

Comment: Thanks Mike W but I'm still left with the data truncated warning

Comment: I've run this in MySQL workbench. I can insert 2.10 into a DECIMAL(4,2) column, but not 2.101 (data truncated) or 102.10 (data out of range). Are you sure you're inserting the values you think you are?

Comment: Yes all is working now, the errors didn't clear for some reason. Thanks